# Form authentication across multiple applications

Tags: asp.net, iis, form-authentication

We are trying to use authentication between two applications on our PC's (Windows 7, IIS 7.5)  and eveything goes fine. But the problem is when we try to publish these sites  (Windows web server 2008, IIS 7.0) the cross authentication didn't work!!

After long invistigation we found that the error occured in the following code which is on the second site:

```
Dim formsCookie As HttpCookie = Request.Cookies(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName)
    If (formsCookie IsNot Nothing) Then
    Else
    ' always null
```

We tried to check the pathes like this in code behind :

```
 Dim ticket As New FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, smsProfile, DateTime.Now, _
                                                       DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), True, AdminSessions.UserObj.Pid, _
                                                       FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath)
    Dim hash As String = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket)
    Dim cookie As New HttpCookie(
       FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,
       hash)
    If (ticket.IsPersistent) Then
        cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration
    End If
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie)
    Response.Redirect(smsPortal)
```

in the web.config:

```
       <authentication mode="Forms">

        <forms name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" domain="mydomain.com.jo" loginUrl="http://..." protection="All" path="/"/>

    </authentication>
```

Kindly advice us what is the difference between IIS in local PC and the Server.

Thanks.

Comment: are they both published to the same domain?

Comment: Yes in the same domain, every one is in separete sub domain.
ex : sub1.mydomain.com.jo , sub2.mydomain.com.jo

Comment: Is there any spesific configuration for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is highly likely that the browser is not sending the authentication cookie from the first site to the second site. Check the cookie path and the domain. Both sites must be on the same domain, and the cookie path must be set to a common root.

See this link for more details:
[Cookie Domains and Paths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Domain_and_Path)

To aid in troubleshooting, use a utility such as Fiddler or Firebug to view the cookies being sent in the request, and verify that the authentication cookie set by site 1 (where the user logged in) is also being sent to site 2.

If the sites aren't on the same server, also check if they are using the same machineKey configuration.

Comment: I've edidt my post and mentioned some codes related to the domain and the path.

Comment: Use Fiddler or Firebug to verify that the cookie is being sent. If it is not, use the Fiddler/Firebug logs to check the actual cookie path and domain on the cookie from the first site. If it is being sent, the server is receiving it but is unable to validate the ticket, so check to make sure the machineKey settings on all machines hosting the sites are configured the same.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to use firebug it seems that I found the problem. I found that the domin in firebug grid didn't show me my domain for .ASPXFORMSAUTH, it show me only he first sub domain. when I tried to change it manually to my domain (.mydomain.com.jo) it's work fine.I change that in the web.config file but vain. How can I solve that in my code and configuration file?

Comment: What domain names are you using for the first site (the one you log in to) and the second site? Are the entries for forms authentication the same in both web.configs? It really does sound like a cookie scope issue if the cookie is not being sent to the second site. Have you tried placing a period before the shared portion of the domain name?